# Is it ok to have multiple nibs with App delegate object in it?

Tags: cocoa

I have two nibs in my application, and was wondering if having one instance of the same app delegate in each one is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be the same object (unless the app delegate is the File's Owner). Any object you drag into a NIB file will be instantiated if the NIB is loaded. Only the File's Owner and First Responder reference existing objects outside the NIB. Since only one object can be your application delegate, your approach will not work.